# How can I not count an child block (example .child span) when clicking on a block?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I not count a child block  (example `.child span`)  when clicking on a block?

If you click on the block `.child` it's fine. But if your click hits the block `.child span` there's an error

```js
var parent = document.querySelector('.parent');
var childLength = document.querySelectorAll('.child').length;
var countClick = 0;

parent.onclick = function(event) {

  var target = event.target;

  if (target.className == 'child') {
    target.className = 'child child-click';

    setTimeout(function() {
      target.className = 'child child-hide';
    }, 3000);
  }

  console.log(countClick);
  countClick++;

  if (childLength == countClick) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      parent.innerHTML = 'All right';
    }, 3000);

  }

}
```

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
}

.child {
  padding: 15px;
  background: #ccc;
  margin: 10px;
}

.child-click {
  background: #f00;
}

.child-hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"><span>1</span></div>
  <div class="child"><span>2</span></div>
  <div class="child"><span>3</span></div>
  <div class="child"><span>4</span></div>
</div>
```

Here's my code on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/31hg5394/).

How can this problem be solved?

Thank you. I will be glad to any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the closest element which has a `.child` class with [.closest()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) like so:

```
var target = event.target.closest('.child');
```

```js
var parent = document.querySelector('.parent');
var childLength = document.querySelectorAll('.child').length;
var countClick = 0;

parent.onclick = function(event) {

  if(event.target === parent) {
      console.log("return cause it's the parent");
      return;
  }

  var target = event.target.closest('.child');
  
  if (target.className == 'child') {
    target.className = 'child child-click';

    setTimeout(function() {
      target.className = 'child child-hide';
    }, 3000);
  }

  console.log(countClick);
  countClick++;

  if (childLength == countClick) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      parent.innerHTML = 'All right';
    }, 3000);

  }

}
```

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
}

.child {
  padding: 15px;
  background: #ccc;
  margin: 10px;
}

.child-click {
  background: #f00;
}

.child-hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"><span>1</span></div>
  <div class="child"><span>2</span></div>
  <div class="child"><span>3</span></div>
  <div class="child"><span>4</span></div>
</div>
```

is that what you want?

**Option 2** Have a look at this. It's another how you could solve your problems with setting the event listener directly to the child elements. Code should be self explanatory but leave a comment if something is not clear.

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.child');
var countClick = 0;

elements.forEach(function(element){
    element.addEventListener('click', function(){

        element.classList.add('child-click');
        
        setTimeout(function() {
            element.classList.add('child-hide');
        }, 3000);
         
        console.log(countClick);
        countClick++;
        
        if (elements.length == countClick) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                element.parentNode.innerHTML = 'All right';
            }, 3000);

        }
    });

});
```

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
}

.child {
  padding: 15px;
  background: #ccc;
  margin: 10px;
}

.child-click {
  background: #f00;
}

.child-hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"><span>1</span></div>
  <div class="child"><span>2</span></div>
  <div class="child"><span>3</span></div>
  <div class="child"><span>4</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what is needed

Comment: The question is: how not to count clicks if you click between blocks?

Comment: @ivansimonov007 I've updated the answer. Especially check out option 2! you will like it.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the target is `span` or not. If target is `span` change the target to it's parent:

```js
var parent = document.querySelector('.parent');
var childLength = document.querySelectorAll('.child').length;
var countClick = 0;

parent.onclick = function(event) {

  var target = event.target;
  target = target.nodeName == 'SPAN'? target.parentNode : target;
  
  if (target.className == 'child') { 
    target.className = 'child child-click';

    setTimeout(function() {
      target.className = 'child child-hide';
    }, 3000);
  }

  console.log(countClick);
  countClick++;

  if (childLength == countClick) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      parent.innerHTML = 'All right';
    }, 3000);

  }

}
```

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
}

.child {
  padding: 15px;
  background: #ccc;
  margin: 10px;
}

.child-click {
  background: #f00;
}

.child-hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"><span>1</span></div>
  <div class="child"><span>2</span></div>
  <div class="child"><span>3</span></div>
  <div class="child"><span>4</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could change the target to point to the correct element instead of duplicating so much code which does the same.